# This OpenGL Code won't render in the main loop

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

When I set my view and model matrix uniform in the mainloop nothing will be drawn to the screen while if I put it outside of the mainloop the rectangle will be rendered.

```cpp
// This is main.cpp

#include "Shader.hpp"
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include "glm/ext/matrix_clip_space.hpp"

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 800
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 600

void CheckOpenGLError(bool exit_on_error)
{
    GLenum err = GL_NO_ERROR;
    std::cout << "CHECKING OPENGL ERROR" << std::endl;
    while((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        if(err == GL_NO_ERROR) {
            break;
        } else {
            if(err == GL_INVALID_ENUM) {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR: GL_INVALID_ENUM" << std::endl;
            } else if(err == GL_INVALID_VALUE) {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR: GL_INVALID_VALUE" << std::endl;
            } else if(err == GL_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR: GL_INVALID_OPERATION" << std::endl;
            } else if(err == GL_STACK_OVERFLOW) {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR: GL_STACK_OVERFLOW" << std::endl;
            } else if(err == GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW) {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR: GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW" << std::endl;
            } else if(err == GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY) {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY" << std::endl;
            } else if(err == GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION) {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR: GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "OPENGL ERROR:" << std::endl;
            }
            if(exit_on_error) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Hello, World", 0, 0);
    if(!window) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create Window" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load opengl functions" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    uint32_t vaoID = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    uint32_t vboID = 0;
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f,-0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        +0.5f,-0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        +0.5f,+0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,+0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*7, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*7, (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); // wireframe mode

    std::string vertSrcPath = "./resources/basic.vert";
    std::string fragSrcPath = "./resources/basic.frag";
    Shader shader = Shader::CreateFromFile(vertSrcPath, fragSrcPath);
    if(shader.IsError()) {
        std::cerr << "SHADER CREATION ERROR " << shader.Why();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    uint32_t eboID;
    uint32_t elements[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &eboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, eboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glUseProgram(shader.GetID());

    glm::mat4 uProj = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 uModel = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 uView = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    uProj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(-55.0f), 
            (float)WINDOW_WIDTH/(float)WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    shader.SetUniform("u_Proj", Shader::Type::MAT4, 1, glm::value_ptr(uProj), false);
    
    /// This will be working since this is outside of the loop
    uModel = glm::rotate(uModel, glm::radians(50.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    uView = glm::translate(uView, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f));
    shader.SetUniform("u_View", Shader::Type::MAT4, 1, glm::value_ptr(uView), false);
    shader.SetUniform("u_Model", Shader::Type::MAT4, 1, glm::value_ptr(uModel), false);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(shader.GetUniformLocation("u_Proj") < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid uniform " << "u_Proj" << std::endl;
    }
    if(shader.GetUniformLocation("u_View") < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid uniform " << "u_View" << std::endl;
    }
    if(shader.GetUniformLocation("u_Model") < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid uniform " << "u_Model" << std::endl;
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        /// This won't be working since this is inside of the loop
        uModel = glm::rotate(uModel, glm::radians(50.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        uView = glm::translate(uView, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f));
        shader.SetUniform("u_View", Shader::Type::MAT4, 1, glm::value_ptr(uView), false);
        shader.SetUniform("u_Model", Shader::Type::MAT4, 1, glm::value_ptr(uModel), false);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, eboID);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(elements)/sizeof(uint32_t), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        CheckOpenGLError(true);
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
/// shader.hpp
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>

std::string LoadFileData(const std::string& filepath);

class Shader {
public:
    enum class Type {
        FLOAT = 0, VEC2, VEC3, VEC4,
        INT, IVEC2, IVEC3, IVEC4,
        MAT3, MAT4
    };

public:
    Shader(const std::string& vertSrc, const std::string& fragSrc);
    ~Shader();

    static Shader CreateFromFile(const std::string& vertSrcPath, const std::string& fragSrcPath);

    inline uint32_t GetID() const { return m_ID; }
    inline bool IsError() const { return m_Error; }
    inline std::string Why() const  { return m_Reason; }
    int GetUniformLocation(const std::string& name) const;
    void SetUniform(const std::string& name, Type type, int count, const void* data, bool transponse);

private:
    uint32_t LoadModule(int type, const std::string& source);
private:
    uint32_t m_ID;

    bool m_Error;
    std::string m_Reason;
};
```

```cpp
/// shader.cpp
#include "Shader.hpp"
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int Shader::GetUniformLocation(const std::string& name) const
{
    int location = glGetUniformLocation(m_ID, name.c_str());
    return location;
}

void Shader::SetUniform(const std::string& name, Type type, int count, const void* data, bool transponse)
{
    int location = GetUniformLocation(name);
    switch (type) {
        case Type::FLOAT: glUniform1fv(location, count, (float*)data); break;
        case Type::VEC2: glUniform2fv(location, count, (float*)data); break;
        case Type::VEC3: glUniform3fv(location, count, (float*)data); break;
        case Type::VEC4: glUniform4fv(location, count, (float*)data); break;
        case Type::INT: glUniform1iv(location, count, (int*)data); break;
        case Type::IVEC2: glUniform2iv(location, count, (int*)data); break;
        case Type::IVEC3: glUniform3iv(location, count, (int*)data); break;
        case Type::IVEC4: glUniform4iv(location, count, (int*)data); break;
        case Type::MAT3: glUniformMatrix3fv(location, count, transponse ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE, (float*)data); break;
        case Type::MAT4: glUniformMatrix4fv(location, count, transponse ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE, (float*)data); break;
    }
}

Shader::Shader(const std::string& vertSrc, const std::string& fragSrc)
    : m_Error(false)
{
    uint32_t vertModule = 0, fragModule = 0;
    vertModule = LoadModule(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertSrc);
    if(!m_Error) {
        fragModule = LoadModule(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragSrc);
        if(!m_Error) {
            m_ID = glCreateProgram();
            glAttachShader(m_ID, vertModule);
            glAttachShader(m_ID, fragModule);
            glLinkProgram(m_ID);
            int success;
            glGetProgramiv(m_ID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if(!success) {
                char infoLog[512];
                m_Error = true;
                glGetProgramInfoLog(m_ID, sizeof(infoLog), NULL, infoLog);
                m_Reason.append(infoLog);
            }
            glDeleteShader(fragModule);
        }
        glDeleteShader(vertModule);
    }
}

Shader::~Shader()
{
    glDeleteProgram(m_ID);
}

uint32_t Shader::LoadModule(int type, const std::string& source)
{
    const char* realSrc = source.c_str();
    uint32_t module = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(module, 1, &realSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(module);

    int success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(module, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        char infoLog[512];
        m_Error = true;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(module, sizeof(infoLog), NULL, infoLog);
        m_Reason.append(infoLog);
        return 0;
    }

    return module;
}

Shader Shader::CreateFromFile(const std::string& vertSrcPath, const std::string& fragSrcPath)
{
    std::string vertSrc = LoadFileData(vertSrcPath);
    std::string fragSrc = LoadFileData(fragSrcPath);
    return Shader(vertSrc, fragSrc);
}

std::string LoadFileData(const std::string& filepath) 
{
    std::ifstream f(filepath);
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string tmp;
    while(!f.eof()) {
        std::getline(f, tmp);
        ss << tmp << std::endl;
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

I am expecting that the code when I put the uniform inside the mainloop and outside on the mainloop would draw the rectangle.

Comment: Both matrices uModel and uView must be restored to identity matrix (in loop) before calling rotate/translate.

Comment: Thankyou very much that's why the tutorial do the model and view matrix initialization inside the loop.